# Android - Compare Thumbnail Bitmaps and Normal Image Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap thumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bmap, 44, 44);
```

how to compare bmap and thumbImage and find which one is thumbnail and one normal?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `extractThumbnail` code

It is only a scaling the bitmap.

```
matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
Bitmap thumbnail = transform(matrix, source, width, height,OPTIONS_SCALE_UP | options);
return thumbnail;
```

So my suggestion would be to check the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the image that you want to compare or check.